# SHOUTcast Radio Streaming Not Working For Kitkat

Tags: android, audio, stream, streaming, audio-streaming

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sirius.fm.radio here is my application url.

in which i am streaming audio from shout cast, It was working fine, Until android release kitkat update, recently i faced issue with that when i run application on android kitkat, it doesn't stream radio in kitkat OS version.

Here is my stream url i am using

http://s8.voscast.com:7112

And Here is error log i am getting on kitkat version

```
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425): Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=http://s8.voscast.com:7112
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425): java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ICY 200 OK
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer.downloadAudioIncrement(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:117)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio.doInBackground(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:88)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio.doInBackground(StreamingMediaPlayer.java:1)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-17 06:15:22.911: E/com.sirius.fm.radio.StreamingMediaPlayer$startRadio(1425):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-17 06:15:22.941: E/on post exte(1425): post exte
```

In all other version of android like `Micromax Canvas 4 A210` , `Samsung Galaxy s3` etc.. Which doesn't have kitkat version it works fine.

While in kitkat Devices Like `Lg Optimus` , `Nexus 5` , `Nexus 4` It doesn't works, it shows above error

Any Help/Guide Line will be appreciated.

Thanks Any Way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got solution

I replace below method with new one

```
URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
        cn.setRequestProperty("Icy-metadata", "1");
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
        }
```

replace above method with new one method described below

```
final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 60 * 1000; // 30s
              final int READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 85 * 1000; // 45s

         OkHttpClient client = new com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient();
            client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            client.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
           OkUrlFactory okUrlFact= new OkUrlFactory(client);

        HttpURLConnection con=   okUrlFact.open(new URL(mediaUrl) );
        con.setRequestProperty("Icy-metadata", "1");
        con.connect();
```

Hope it will help some one

Thanks

Comment: Aamir, I am not finding OkUrlFactory class in okhttp jar. It is present in okhttp-urlconnection.jar but as package names are same, it is trying to find in okhttp.jar . Is there any solution for that?